# Android :delete multi selected images

Tags: android

Hello stackoverflow I'm trying to develop an application that display images from SD card and from captured camera and also allow user to delete the images using a check box. I'm able to display images from SD card and camera with Check-box but I'm unable to delete the specific or multiple images which has been ticked by the user dynamically. Here is my MainActivity.java

```
imgDeleteImagesFromGallery = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgDeleteImage);
        imgDeleteImagesFromGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                ArrayList<String> selectedItems = gridAdapter.getCheckedItems();
                Log.e("data "," size = "+imgItemArray.size() + " & selectedItems size = " +selectedItems.size() + "Total photos selected: "+selectedItems.size());
                Log.e(AddPost.class.getSimpleName(), "Selected Items: " + selectedItems.toString() + " Data Selected Items: "+ imgItemArray.toString());

                for(int i = 0 ; i < selectedItems.size()-1 ; i++)
                {
                    imgItemArray.remove(i);
                }

               gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

And here is my getView() method from adapter class

```
 @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View row = convertView;
            final ViewHolder holder;

            if (row == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
                row.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            }
            final BitmapItems item = imgItemArray.get(position);
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getBitmap());

            holder.checkbox.setTag(position);
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position));
            holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);
            return row;
        }

        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
                Log.e("Is ", " Checked !!!");
                imgItemArray.remove((Integer) buttonView.getTag());
            }
        };
```

When i tick first 2 images for deletion it getting error of **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1**

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < selectedItems.size()-1 ; i++)
                {
                    imgItemArray.remove(i);
                }
```

Here is my log cat information

```
10-27 10:43:31.945    4375-4375/com.example.tazeen.classnkk E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tazeen.classnkk, PID: 4375
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:403)
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AddPost$2.onClick(AddPost.java:248)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19748)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you have removed the first element from the ArrayList, its size is reduced to 1. Now, the max index available in the arraylist becomes 0. Try this code code instead:

```
    for(int i = selectedItems.size()-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
            {
                imgItemArray.remove(i);
            }
```

Edit:
You need to change your gridAdapter. It should not return an ArrayList of selected items, it should return an arraylist of selected indices. Then your `selectedItems` list would contain the selected indices. After this, do :

```
    for(int i = selectedItems.size()-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
            {
                imgItemArray.remove(selectedItems.get(i));
            }
```

Comment: :Thanks for the reply . I used your code lines But when i select last image it delete first image .  how can i delete specific selected imaages from that position.

Comment: images are not deleted even again change in code.But  selectedItems = ArrayList<String> selectedItems = gridAdapter.getCheckedItems();  and  imgItemArray is = ArrayList<BitmapItems> imgItemArray = new ArrayList<BitmapItems>(); It is possible to delete images ?

Comment: @androidTag That is what I said in my edited answer, that you need to change the implementation of your gridadapter, so that your selectedItems becomes ArrayList<int>

Comment: See i have change something like this whatever you saying =  ArrayList<Integer> selectedItems = gridAdapter.getCheckedItems(); But it shows Incompatible type .

Comment: @androidTag What part of "you need to change implementation of your gridadapter" did you not understand, dude?